# mysql - importing Tablespace: Lost connection during query

Tags: mysql

iam trying to recover innodb table which has 1.5M rows from ibd file ( 5.5 GB )

this is the exact steps i do:

1. getting create table query using mysqlfrm command
2. create the table
3. discard tablespace
4. moving the new tablespace to the db directory
5. import tablespace

and i'm getting this error :-

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

is there any way to import it ??

Answer (score 0):

**max_allowed_packet**

**wait_timeout**

max_allowed_packet is too low will have timeout issues from mysqldump restore.
If you are waiting more than the time specified in the configuration then it might explain the loss of connection.